# Does absolute continuity of measures imply a relation between the $L_p$ spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Say $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ is some measure space, and let $\sigma$ be some other measure on $(X,\mathcal{B})$ such that $\sigma\ll\mu$. What can one say about the relation between $L_p(\mu)$ and $L_p(\sigma)$?

Comment: Are you assuming either one is finite or $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: If $g=\mathrm d \sigma /\mathrm d\mu$, then $L_p(\sigma)=\{f\text{ measurable}\mid fg\in L_p(\mu)\}$.

Comment: My question is phrased in a very general manner. If imposing some assumptions leads to interesting results I'll be happy if someone writes about it.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/190063/8157

Comment: @user25640 What kind of "relation" would you like to have?